# Quantitative aptitude type question

Tags: probability

A cricketer whose bowling average is 12.4  runs per wicket, takes 5 wickets for 26  runs and thereby decreases his average 0.4. the number of wickets taken by him till the last match was?????

Comment: What is probable here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the number of wickets taken by him till the last match was $x$

So, the total runs given away was $=12.4x$

Now the total runs given away $=12.4x+26$

and the total wickets taken $=x+5$

So, $$\dfrac{12.4x+26}{x+5}=12.4-0.4$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of wicket taken till the last match = x
so run conceded = 12.4x
in the 2nd case , number of wicket = x+5
run conceded = 12(x+5)
so 12.4x + 26 = 12(x+5)
12.4x + 26 = 12x + 60
0.4x = 24
x = 60

you can read the concepts here https://www.handakafunda.com/averages-concepts-from-arithmetic-how-to-apply-in-cat-questions/

Comment: Use LaTeX please.